# How can i get Number in onChangeText in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have created a userInput in React Native

> const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState("");

```
  (<View style={styles.InputContainer}>
  <Text>Fisrt Name</Text>
  <TextInput
    value={first_name}
    onChangeText={(text) => setFirstName(text)}
    placeholder="John"
    style={styles.textInput}
  />
</View>;)
```

and `first_name` is a `string`
and I have another field for which I want a `number`

> const [fabricLength, setFabricLength] = useState(0);

```
 (<View style={styles.InputContainer}>
                  <Text>S Fabric Length</Text>
                  <TextInput
                     value={fabricLength}
                     onValueChange={(text) => setFabricLength(text)}
                     placeholder="Enter Fabric Length"
                     keyboardType="number-pad"
                     style={styles.textInput}
              />
            </View>;)
```

whatever number I type I am still getting `string`

How can I get `number`?

Answer (score 1):

Text input is always returning string, if you want user to enter only numbers you can set  keyboardType to numeric, but if you want to use them as number later in your app, just use `Number("yourStringNumber"):`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your string value to integer using parseInt().

Answer (score 1):

`initialize` the hook with '0', then you must convert the value obtained from `inputtext` to Number()

For example:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState('0');

     const count = () =>{
         setCounter(String(Number(counter) + 1))
         console.log(counter);
     }
```

I hope it helps you